# Yii Framework : call Controller's function from CAction class

Tags: php, yii

I want to make a modular Controller by separating Actions in different class.
The problem is some of the actions are calling a private function of the controler.

Controller :

```
class ApiController extends Controller
{
    public function actions()
    {
        return array(
            'index'=>'application.controllers.api.IndexAction',
        );
    }

    ..........

    private function _sendResponse($status = 200, $body = '', $content_type = 'text/html')
    {
        // some code
    }
}
```

In IndexAction.php I tried like this, but doesn't work :

```
class IndexAction extends CAction
{
    public function run()
    {
            $this->getController()->_sendResponse(204); //this error
    }
```

}

the exception is

```
ApiController and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "_sendResponse".
```

Is this possible what i'm trying to do?
am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looks like you try to access a private Method out of the Scope of your Class. Not even Classes that inherit can access a private Method. 
Try `public function _sendResponse()`